# Network design question for datacenter

Tags: cisco, network, design, cisco-nexus

We have new customer and they said their traffic requirement is `~40GB` so i am planning to order some hardware and have some question or doubt in mind.

I am planning to put `Nexus 5000` for Core layer for L3 routing with HSRP and for Access Layer `Nexus 3000`

My question is does Nexus 5000 are capable to run full `40G` IP traffic?

or any other suggestion would be welcome.

[image]

Comment: Is it really 40 GB (over what time period?), or is it a bandwidth requirement of 40 Gbps?

Comment: I would also strongly suggest you have a link between the two Nexus 5Ks. Then, you can eliminate HSRP.

Comment: at present 40G but it may go 60G over the time but not more than that, Yes we will have link between both switch it was just missing in diagram.

Comment: What do you mean by G? Is it giga _bytes_ (and over what period of time) or is it the usual bandwidth of _bits_ per second? `40GB` would be gigabytes, normally a measure of storage, but `40 Gb` would be a bandwidth measurement. What, specifically, do you mean by `~40GB`?

Comment: It is 40Gbps (sorry for GB) so all i need to know does `N5K` capable to handle that IP traffic on QSFP+ port

Comment: The Nexus 5K, in general, can easily handle 40 Gbps (over 1 Tbps). There are some new models designed specifically for the 40 Gb QSFP.

Comment: Can I use nexus 3064 switch for core?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70647/discussion-between-satish-and-ron-maupin).

Comment: Can we use `N55-M4Q` module in Nexus 5548UP switch to get 40G ports for internet pipe?

Comment: @Satish Please accept the answer if it helped you in any way. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The 5600-series can switch 40G at line rate (...as in full 40Gbit/s flows) but won't ever be able to switch full 100G interfaces (nb - fabric is limited to 40G flows).  The 5500 can only support 40G in a 4x10G mode (...no flow over 10Gbit/s).  The 50x0 is strictly 10G only.
2. Unless you actively need certain features (specifically native FC termination or FabricPath) the 5K isn't really a great choice for a new network build.  Most of the 3K or 9K line will be both substantially cheaper and faster, with most modern devices supporting ports that can support 100G or 40G.
3. If you're trying to connect to an upstream ISP then the 5K (...even 5600) **really** isn't ideal, as they weren't built to support much ACL density and have very small routing tables.  Other models (both within the Cisco Nexus line and from other vendors) will be **far** more appropriate to task.
4. When you consider modern switching platforms it's likely that you'll find that a higher-speed aggregation switch (...consisting of mostly 40/100G ports) might make a lot more sense.  The access switches would then also connect at 40 or 100 and can then supply whatever speed is necessary.

Comment: Thanks! You are suggesting I should use N3K in core with 40G interface, any specific model you suggest?

Comment: We have `Nexus 3064QP` L3 switches can i use them for core?

Comment: In the Cisco world, (9K or 3K) - take a look at 9236C or 3232C for 40/100G switching.  If you want to do pure 40G (wouldn't suggest it) check out the 3132Q-V or 9272Q.  The 9K versions will tend to be able to support more routes and more ACL's.  I'd suggest taking a look at the respective data sheets and scalability to see which best fits your requirements.

Comment: 3064PQ has 48 ports of 10G and 4 ports of 40G.  It has a pretty limited table size and number of ACL's.  It's been end-of-sale for 5+ years and is almost beyond vendor support.  It's probably not what I'd use to build a new network.

Comment: @mxrx problem is our ISP going to provide 4x10G (40G bonded link), its not going to be single 40G fiber. so i am looking for 10G switches. when you say limited table size and number of ACL? We are not going to run any ACL etc at this point.

Comment: You can break out many/most 40- or 100- gig ports into 4x10 (or 4x25, 2x50, etc depending on hardware) with appropriate optics.  My point about table size/ACL is about the number/type of filters that can be applied (still potentially important for temporary blocking) and the number of routes the box can handle.  The last point may be of particular interest depending on how many internal/external routes you need to carry.

Comment: we have no plan to run any dynamic routing protocol, it’s going to be default route. Also I looked at nexus 9396PX that switch also looking promising, what do you think?

Comment: 9396PX is certainly newer than a 3064 (or any of the 5K's, for that matter) but is EOL (announced as of August of 2017, so 5+ years of support remaining).  It was supplanted by the 93180YC-EX or -FX.  The new switches have 48 100M/1G/10G/25G SFP+ and 6 40/100G QSFP28's and are 1U (vs the 2U 9396) and are a big step up in performance and capacity.